# flutter error: The method 'combineLatest4' isn't defined for the type 'Observable'

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, observable, rxdart

My project never update for 6 months (written by someone & last build was successful), but today I want to update it but face some errors:

> lib/src/blocs/account/account_bloc.dart:69:33: Error: **The getter 'Observable' isn't defined for the class 'AccountBloc'.**
>
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named '**Observable**'.

it seems `Observable` come from [rxdart library](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart), but I'm not sure about it.

My Code:

```
//Merging username and password streams
Stream<bool> get saveValid => Observable.combineLatest4(nameStream, phoneNumberStream, emailStream, addressStream, (name, phoneNumber, email, address) => true);
```

`rxdart` version in my `pubspec.yaml` : `rxdart: ">=0.18.1 <0.24.1"`

any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RxDart v0.23 replaced the Observable class with extension methods. You now need to use the static `Rx.combineLatest4()` instead. If you look at the change log for RxDart on pub.dev you'll see you can run a package `rxdart_codemod` to migrate your RxDart code.

https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Rx/combineLatest4.html

Comment: Hi thank you.  but  why plugin update so frequently and has major change? i will rethink in future to write another apps using flutter. i cant imagine how many errors I will get for 2 years of not updating projects

Comment: I would think any package that is below version 1 is likely to have frequent changes, with some of them being breaking changes. In your example you have specified you'll accept RxDart between versions 0.18.1 and 0.23.0 (which in this case includes that breaking change). If you're concerned about future updates breaking your code, you could use a fixed version number in your pubspec: `rxdart: 0.23.0` for example.

Comment: The `rxdart: ">=0.18.1 <0.24.1"`, it's because of my change after 3 days' pain to solve the flutter compass error because of plugin update. the previous developer does not face those errors.